# Devise - How to display user that updated others post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, controller

I would like users to be able to create/update my "Person" resource, including overwriting each other. Currently I'm able to capture the user who created the initial "Person" but i can't figure out how to capture and display the user that updated the resource.

For example if *user 1* creates an item, then *user 2* updates this item, I would like to display that this item was most recently edited by *user 2*.

Here's my controller, any help would be much appreciated thanks!

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /people
  # GET /people.json
  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  # GET /people/1
  # GET /people/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /people/new
  def new
    @person = current_user.person.build
  end

  # GET /people/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /people
  # POST /people.json
  def create
    @person = current_user.person.build(person_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /people/1
  # PATCH/PUT /people/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /people/1
  # DELETE /people/1.json
  def destroy
    @person.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to people_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_person
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :twitter, :facebook, :instagram, :vine)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way for doing it is to maintain the a column called updated_by and store the current user when its updated as @Andrey mentioned in previous comment.
But if your looking for a more extensive for tracking you can use **auditable** gem
You can check this out : 
https://github.com/harley/auditable

Answer (score 1):

Create `updated_by` column in `posts` table, and each time user updates the post, update the column `updated_by` by the value of `current_user`.